# Adobe distiller: Cambria not found, using Courier

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, print-to-pdf

Whenever I try to print to PDF from an MS Word 2007 document, I get this error:

> Cambria not found, using Courier.

(Even though I believe I removed ALL occurrences of Cambria from the document)

The pdf doesn't get produced actually, all I get is this error log file with that message.

**Edit:**  I found the source of the problem.  It was an MS-Word equation that *insists* on using "Cambria Math" that the distiller was choking over.  I can't seem to get equations to print to pdf though!

Answer (score 12):

When you print in Word, Click on Properties for the Adobe PDF printer, and on that panel, turn off the box that says "Rely on System fonts only; do not use document fonts" ... that will allow Acrobat to embed the Cambria from MS Word into the PDF itself.

Comment: I'm having this same problem as well and have been looking for a way to set this to a default, but have not found anything yet. Any ideas?

Comment: Open the printer from the Windows control panel (in Windows 7 click "View devices and printers" under "Hardware and Sound").  Right click on the printer named "Adobe PDF" and select "Printing preferences".  Clearing the "Rely on system fonts only" checkbox here will make that the default setting for the Adobe PDF printer.

Comment: I confirm the "rely on system fonts only;" trick works also when printing PDF using Adobe from Outlook.